# Maven Plugins missing

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

So I tried learning maven and I had no clue what I was doing and removed all my plugins...How can I all of them back?

[image: http://puu.sh/kBapu/7b35ad54ea.png]

Comment: Do you have a backup of your POM file somewhere?

Comment: Do I have a backup? Not sure, I know I have pom.xml in my project

Comment: I mean do you have an _older_ version of the POM?

Comment: I don't have a older version of the POM

Comment: Try to run a simple maven command outside IntelliJ idea, such as mvn clean installed. If everything is ok, then: 1. check maven configuration, especially executable and settings files, 2. Do you have a special maven settings configuration containing proxy config?  Moreover, you can open the maven pom.xml file and then Ctrl+Shift+A and type history, then choose local history. And compare what was changed in the file lately.

Comment: How would I be able to run it outside of Intellij idea?